# Prompting to print all of that type, and calculate the total of that type

Tags: java, methods, printing, call

I have a file that is needed to be read:

```
 public static int start_program1(int rcount,int[]reservation_code,int[]fl_number,String[]last_name,String[]first_name,String[]seat_type,double[]seat_cost)
 {
                String newLine;
                  try
                  {
                    //define a file valuable for Buffered read
                     BufferedReader Reservation_file = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("reservationx.dat"));
                     //read lines in file until there are no more lines in the file to read
                     while ((newLine = Reservation_file.readLine()) != null)
                       {
                         //there is a "#" between each data item in each line
                          StringTokenizer delimiter = new StringTokenizer(newLine,"#");
                          rcount=rcount+1;
                          reservation_code[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                          fl_number[rcount] = Integer.parseInt(delimiter.nextToken());
                          last_name[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                          first_name[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                          seat_type[rcount] =delimiter.nextToken();
                          seat_cost[rcount] = Double.parseDouble(delimiter.nextToken());
                        }//while loop
                       Reservation_file.close();
                    }//end try
                catch (IOException error)
                  {
                  //there was an error on the file writing
                  System.out.println("Error on file read " + error);
                  }//error on read
                return rcount;
          }//end start_system1
```

The file being read (reservations.dat) is simply below: (Wasn't sure of an easier way to post this)
(reservation code#flight number#last name#first name#seat type#seat cost)

1189#1234#Smith#James#coach#299.99#
1190#9876#Jones#Marie#coach#150.00#
1191#2000#Atkins#John#first#789.00#
1192#1000#Gallo#James#first#465.00#
1193#4567#Marion#Kevin#business#300.00#
1194#4444#Johnson#Greg#business#765.99#
1195#8888#Brown#Andrew#first#567.39#
1196#4567#Green#Eric#coach#234.00#
1197#9876#Thomas#Chris#business#1900.99#
1198#7777#Hilling#Cara#first#876.76#
1199#2222#Cole#James#coach#256.99#
1200#9281#Bartko#Grant#business#896.00#
1201#2000#Best#Curtis#first# 543.99#
1202#1000#Campbell#Nicholas#coach#287.00#
1203#4444#Dietz#Merrialyce#coach# 219.00#
1204#9281#Duran#Alexander#business#690.00#
1205#2892#Gurung#Suraj#first# 789.99#
1206#7777#Kumpfmiller#Ryan#first#278.99#
1207#4444#Mccomb#David#coach#451.99#
1208#8888#Mclain#Jaime#coach#199.00#
1209#9876#Mullen#Matthew#coach#189.00#
1210#1234#Nguyen#Tommy#coach#299.00#
1211#1234#Ossler#Aimee#coach#300.00#
1212#7777#Polenavitch#Michael#coach#198.99#
1213#2222#Raymond#Chase#first#908.99#
1214#2222#Rosales#David#coach#216.99#
1215#2892#Schwartz#Dustin#business#987.00#
1216#4444#Short#Samuel#coach#245.99#
1217#8888#Soltis#Josh#coach#178.00#
1218#1234#Webster#Ronald#business#892.00#
1219#1234#Wielock#William#first#589.00#
1220#2892#Bonelli#Andrew#coach#178.00#
1221#4444#Bright#Adam#coach#235.00#
1222#9876#Clymer#Jesse#coach#568.00#
1223#4444#Costello#Michael#coach#200.00#
1234#7777#Currin#Sean#business#908.00#
1225#1000#Farrar#Gary#first#588.00#
1226#1000#Finn#Lynn#business#799.00#
1227#4567#Freise#Brian#coach#254.00#
1228#4567#Huang#Pao-Jen#coach# 199.00#
1229#4567#Kamani#Nelson#coach#150.00#
1230#2000#Loughner#Ryan#coach#175.00#
1231#2000#Menzies#Adam#coach#199.00#
1232#1234#Neupane#Kiran#coach# 135.00#
1233#1234#Nickel#Brandon#first#999.00#
1234#7777#Ropchack#Joseph#first#899.00#
1235#7777#Whitten#Walter#coach#786.99#
1236#4444#Woods#Mary#coach#299.00#
1237#4444#Xing#Zhenli#coach#126.00#

Here is the method, doing the calculation in question:

```
 public static void seat_value(int rcount,int[]reservation_code,int[]fl_number,String[]last_name,String[]first_name,String[]seat_type,double[]seat_cost)
    {
     int i;
     double total=0;
     String search_seat = "";
     String output = "Enter the Seat Type you are searching for";
     search_seat = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                               output, " ",
                                               JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);

     for (i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
        //CHECK IF coach, first, or business
          if(seat_type[i].equals("coach"))
             {
                 total=total+seat_cost[i];
             }
          if (seat_type.equals("first"))
             {
              total=total+seat_cost[i];
             }
          if(seat_type.equals("business"))
             {
              total=total+seat_cost[i];   
             }
     }
      System.out.println("The total for " +search_seat+ " = " +total);
    }
```

My issue in detail is this: Whenever I have it prompt for a type ("coach", "first", "business") 
I cannot figure out how to get it to print ALL reservations of THAT type & TOTAL COST of THAT type? 
CURRENTLY GETTING:     2051.97             8900.94         8094.45
ACTUAL TOTALS:         7230.93         8295.11         8138.98
                       COACH           FIRST           BUSINESS

PS, you will obviously call these methods

Hope this is explains it well.

Answer (score 0):

Well in this loop:

```
     for (i = 0; i <=rcount; ++i) {
    //CHECK IF coach, first, or business
      if(seat_type[i].equals("coach"))
         {
             total=total+seat_cost[i];
         }
      if (seat_type[i].equals("first"))
         {
          total=total+seat_cost[i];
         }
      if(seat_type[i].equals("business"))
         {
          total=total+seat_cost[i];   
         }
 }
```

you add the cost to the same total every single time regardless of the seat type. So you will end up with the total of all the seats each time.

Basically heres what you are doing in english:

I am going to go through each customer. For each customer, I will do the following:

- If their seat type is coach, add it to the total.
- If their seat type is first, add it to the total.
- If their seat type is business, add it to the total.

Basically, you are adding every customers ticket price to the total because every customer will satisfy one of the three conditions you are testing.

You should replace the three if statements with the following:

```
if(seat_type[i].equals(search_seat)) {
    total += seat_cost[i];
    System.out.println( reservation_code[i] + "," + fl_number[i] + "," + last_name[i] + "," + first_name[i] + "," + seat_type[i] + "," + seat_cost[i]);
}
```

Comment: correction, I made a mistake in my previous code.

Thank you, 

I get the correct totals of (anyway to fix the decimal points?)

The total for coach = 2051.9700000000003
The total for business = 8900.94
The total for first = 8094.450000000002

Comment: I alsovcannot figure out how to get it to print ALL reservations of THAT type "searched"

Comment: The decimal point can be fixed like so `System.out.printf("%.2f", my_number)`

Comment: To print all of the reservations of that type you can simply put a statement in that if clause that prints out that specific reservation.

Comment: Is there any way you could help with that?

I am actually a beginner haha

Comment: Just kidding, I actually went through and calculated the totals from my reservation files and the totals are wrong. (I thought they were correct, but still hundreds->thousands off the correct totals

Comment: Ive added a print line to the if statement. Try that and see if all of  right reservations are printed out when you use it.

Comment: NO, I got:

2222,1199,Cole,James,coach,256.99
The total for coach = 2051.9700000000003